# DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I searched throughout the website for the error

I am getting this error while binding a dropdown list.

> DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name "APPRAISER_ID"

Here's my code:

```
DataSet DSEmployee = new DataSet();
DSEmployee = ws_service.GetReportingDtl(user);
ddlEmployee.DataTextField = "APPRAISER_ID";
ddlEmployee.DataValueField = "APPRAISER_ID";
ddlEmployee.DataSource = DSEmployee.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToString();
ddlEmployee.DataBind();
```

And in my webservice.

```
string strQ = "select employee_id,appraiser_id from kirti_pms_reporting where appraiser_id='" + varAppraiserId.ToString() + "'";
```

My Inline code for dropdown list is

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  CssClass="vlu">
```

What I missed here? The same code works fine in another aspx page.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you bind a string to your `DataSource`

```
ddlEmployee.DataSource = DSEmployee.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToString();
```

And a string don't have a property `APPRAISER_ID`.

```
select employee_id,appraiser_id from kirti_pms_reporting where appraiser_id='" + 
varAppraiserId.ToString() + "'";
```

Is not a good idea because you could run into SqlInjection.

Comment: Note: the reason for the 'System.Char' error message is that the datasource should be Enumerable. That String *is* enumerable: it's a list of chars. And a Char doesn't have that 'Appraiser_id'.

Comment: @HansKesting A String is not just a list of chars, or array of chars, in .NET.

Comment: @dknaack - no, a string is not a list of chars, but it **is** an `IEnumerable<Char>`, which is what counts here.

Comment: @HansKesting Yes `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, but other interfaces too. right

Comment: Can you please help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075489/how-to-populate-dropdownlist-based-on-a-datatable